# Which equation is more simplified?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A question needed me to find the equation for a line. This was my answer:
$$y=-\frac15(x-17)$$
However, the answer given by my textbook is:
$$y-3=-\frac15(x-2)$$
It essentially has the same value. However, is there a reason why the answer is manipulated in such a way that instead of $y$, it is now $y-3$ on the left hand side?

Comment: Hint: $\frac{17}{5}=3+\frac{2}{5}$

Comment: There is no reason. Instead, is more convenient express like you expressed :)

Comment: @Plato You didn't read anything of the question.

Comment: I thought the question was how the two are equal. And I get your point, my apologies. Maybe subtracting $17$ isn't pleasant for some people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, there are three forms of linear equations:  slope-intercept form, point-slope form, and standard form.

Slope-intercept form is in the form $$y=mx+b$$ where $m$ is the slope and $b$ is the $y$-intercept.

Point-slope form is in the form $$y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$$ where $m$ is the slope and $(x_1,y_1)$ is a point that the line passes through.

Standard form is in the form $$Ax+By+C=0$$ where $A,B,C\in\Bbb Z$ and $A>0$.

Most texts will choose to leave equations in one of these forms as by convention they are easiest to recognize and to use.

Answer (score 2):

Of course both are correct, but on Your textbook answer we can immediately see that the line goes through $(2,3)$.